# bind callback is not work in NetFilterQueue with python

Tags: python, packet, packet-sniffers

hi guys i want to make a packet queue  with this simple code :

```
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    print(pkt)


nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(0, print_and_accept)
```

but
"print_and_accept"  is not fire and work !
program doesn't print packet and internet is worked well !
how ?
and how can fix it

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add `nfqueue.run()`

```py
def print_and_accept(pkt):
    print(pkt)

nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(0, print_and_accept)
nfqueue.run()
```

after `nfqueue.bind(0, print_and_accept)` sentence.